# ionic side menu app - change ion-nav-view class

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and i'm pretty lost with the directive.. can't figure out when to use what..

I've started side menu app,

I can't find a way to change ion-nav-bar dircetive class from bar-stable to anything else..

also I don't quite understand how should it work.. does my index.html body tag should only contain

```
    <ion-nav-view>

</ion-nav-view>
```

does anybody knows a good guide for starting with ionic? theirs are so misguiding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the nav bar class changing, check this codepen: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tcIGK

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"animation="no-animation">
```

And yes, for a basic sidemenu application, your body should only contain a nav view. Assuming you are going by their ionic-starter-sidemenu project on github (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/index.html), your body should look like this:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

This just sets up the shell of your app. The more important, meaty part is in a template file that serves as a "parent" or main template which is set up in your app's config. In the case of Ionic, typically you'll be using states:

```
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})
```

You'll notice this points to menu.html (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/templates/menu.html). In that file, the actual sidemenu is set up as well as another nav view where the content of your other templates will go.

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>
```

For some beginner level tutorials, I am going to be a little self serving and suggest my blog:

http://mcgivery.com/tag/ionicframework/

A good starting point is my article on the Structure of an Ionic App which gives a good introduction to the overall, high level details.

http://mcgivery.com/structure-of-an-ionic-app/

And if you have any requests for specific tutorials, feel free to hit me up on Twitter. (@andrewmcgivery)

Hope this helps. :)